# Cant find inviter id for discord server invite

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to find the user id of the person that invited someone to a discord server.. im getting the error

`Ignoring exception in on_member_join Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "main.py", line 164, in on_member_join inviter = member.guild.get_member(inv_user.id) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

My code is

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global count_df
    global inviters_df
    global leavers_df

    inv_user = await tracker.fetch_inviter(member)
    inviter = member.guild.get_member(inv_user.id)
    
    #Update invite counts
    try: #Check to see if the user had an invite count saved already
        count_df.loc[inviter.id]
    except KeyError: #If not, make a new entry for the member
        new_entry = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0]], index=[inviter.id], columns=count_df.columns)
        count_df = count_df.append(new_entry)
    else: #If yes, then add to it
        count_df.loc[inviter.id,"Real"] += 1
    

    #Update inviter/leaver record
    inviters_df = inviters_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[inviter.id]], index=[member.id], columns=inviters_df.columns))
    inviters_df.to_csv('csv/member_invite_record.csv', index_label='Member')

    try:
        entries =leavers_df.loc[member.id]
    except KeyError:
        return #Member has not left the guild before, no need to update anything
    else:
        for entry in pd.DataFrame([entries]).itertuples():
            if entry.Inviter == inviter.id:
                count_df.loc[inviter.id,"Left"] -= 1
        count_df.to_csv('csv/invite_count.csv', index_label='User_ID')
        leavers_df.drop(labels=member.id, inplace=True)
        leavers_df.to_csv('csv/member_leaver_record.csv', index_label='Leaver')
    
    await give_roles(inviter)
    channel = bot.get_channel(821556573386047518)
    await channel.send(f'{inviter.mention} invited {member.mention} to the server!')
```

Basically im making the user id go into the csv file to keep track of the inviter and how many invites they have. The error is happening at `inviter = member.guild.get_member(inv_user.id)`
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct. However, you require the `Members Intent` this is because the `get_member` requires a Member object which you can only get with the Members Intent.

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. You might also want to enable `Presence intent` as you may require it in the future and it saves you time going back and doing it again.

You will then have to edit your bot variable like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

Comment: Im pretty sure i have this enabled but i will double check. Thanks!

Comment: If I have solved your issue please mark it as correct @ColeTMK